# upgrade python version using pip

Tags: python, upgrade, pip

So I have python 2.7.3 installed on Windows 7 64 bit and I want to do an incremental upgrade to version 2.7.5.  I have pip installed and it works fine; I just installed Django using it.

I ran into this command:
pip install --upgrade 'python>=2.7,<2.7.99'

Now it forces pip to download the latest version that is not Python 3 which is what I want.
2.7.5 starts downloading and I get the following error:

```
    Downloading/unpacking python>=2.7,<2.7.99
      Downloading Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2 (12.1MB): 12.1MB downloaded
      Running setup.py egg_info for package python
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
          File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-name\python\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
            COMPILED_WITH_PYDEBUG = ('--with-pydebug' in sysconfig.get_config_var("CONFIG_ARGS"))
        TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-name\python\setup.py", line 33, in <module>

        COMPILED_WITH_PYDEBUG = ('--with-pydebug' in sysconfig.get_config_var("CONFIG_ARGS"))

    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

    ----------------------------------------
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\name\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-name\python
```

Also I am new to pip.  When I cancel a download is that safe?  I typed install "pip install python" and it started downloading version python version 3. So I cancelled.  That won't override my main python 2.7.3 install?

Curious.

Comment: Any limitation for you to not use the 2.7.5 windows installer from python.org ?

Comment: Good point.  I kind of want to maximize the pip usage though.

Comment: Did I break anything by running "pip install python" while I had 2.7.3 already installed?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`pip` is designed to upgrade python packages and not to upgrade python itself. `pip` shouldn't try to upgrade python when you ask it to do so.

Don't type `pip install python` but use an installer instead.

Comment: That clarified what I was thinking.  I want to be clear if I broke anything regarding my previous question.

Comment: how to install python3 from command line on linux tho? "use an installer" why?

Comment: "use an installer" - How? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, pip comes with python itself.Therefore it carries no meaning for using pip itself to install or upgrade python.
Thus,try to install python through installer itself,visit the site  "https://www.python.org/downloads/" for more help.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That *only* updates pip, not python.

Answer (score -1):

This will update the python version (only if it is less than 3)

python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score -8):

```
py -m pip install --upgrade python.
```

Maybe this code will help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).