# How do I upgrade to python 3.8 on Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have tried:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769109/upgade-python-version-using-pip#:~:text=pip%20is%20designed%20to%20upgrade,but%20use%20an%20installer%20instead.&text=Basically%2C%20pip%20comes%20with%20python%20itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769109/upgade-python-version-using-pip#:%7E:text=pip%20is%20designed%20to%20upgrade,but%20use%20an%20installer%20instead.&text=Basically%2C%20pip%20comes%20with%20python%20itself).

[Install Python 3.8 kernel in Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory)

https://kegui.medium.com/how-to-install-mlfinlab-without-error-messages-896e2fb43c2f

None of the proposed solutions work.

I'm struggling to update colab python to 3.8. pip is designed to upgrade python packages and not to upgrade python itself. pip shouldn't try to upgrade python when you ask it to do so. Don't type pip install python but use an installer instead. Basically, pip comes with python itself.

Comment: It's to install mlfinlab. !pip install mlfinlab : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlfinlab (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlfinlab

Comment: mlfinlab 1.0.1 requires numpy==1.20.1, but tensorflow 2.4.1 requires numpy~=1.19.2. I have checked the mlfinlab installation for colab. I have uninstalled tensorflow and upgraded my numpy to 1.20.1. However, the following occurs:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlfinlab (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mlfinlab

Answer (score 0):

MlFinlab has relaxed the hard versioning so you can now install on Colab :)